# Split multiple columns with delimiter and have consistent column names in r

Tags: r, dplyr, split

I have a large data set and here is the sample (the raw data has more columns

```
dta0 = data.frame(cbind(paste(seq(10,15),seq(20,25),sep = ";"),
paste(seq(30,35),seq(40,45),sep = ";")    )     )
colnames(dta0) = c("H1","H2")
```

Here is my desired output

```
desired_dta = data.frame(cbind(seq(10,15),seq(20,25),seq(30,35),seq(40,45)))
colnames(desired_dta) = c("H1_x","H1_y","H2_x","H2_y")
```

How can I name columns like `"H1_x", "H1_y","H2_x", "H2_y" ....`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with `cSplit`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(dta0, names(dta0), sep=";")
#   H1_1 H1_2 H2_1 H2_2
#1:   10   20   30   40
#2:   11   21   31   41
#3:   12   22   32   42
#4:   13   23   33   43
#5:   14   24   34   44
#6:   15   25   35   45
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```r
library(tidyr)

dta0 %>% 
  separate(H1, c("H1_x", "H1_y"), ";") %>% 
  separate(H2, c("H2_x", "H2_y"), ";")
#>   H1_x H1_y H2_x H2_y
#> 1   10   20   30   40
#> 2   11   21   31   41
#> 3   12   22   32   42
#> 4   13   23   33   43
#> 5   14   24   34   44
#> 6   15   25   35   45
```

Or in base R

```r
setNames(as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, lapply(dta0, 
        function(x) do.call(rbind, strsplit(x, ";"))))),
        unlist(lapply(names(dta0), paste0, c("_x", "_y"))))
#>   H1_x H1_y H2_x H2_y
#> 1   10   20   30   40
#> 2   11   21   31   41
#> 3   12   22   32   42
#> 4   13   23   33   43
#> 5   14   24   34   44
#> 6   15   25   35   45
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Is there a way of doing it without manually choosing and naming each column? My data set is so large.

Comment: @AllanCameron I like the second approach very clean and without package dependence!

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Should I have a code choosing N columns? The sample only has H1 and H2 but I have a total of 24 Hs.

Comment: @Johnlegend2 This will split any number of H columns without specifying them (as long as you only have H columns)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using `separate_rows()` then reshape to long and after that reshape to wide. Here the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
dta0 %>% mutate(id=1:n()) %>%
  separate_rows(c(H1,H2),sep = ';') %>%
  group_by(id) %>% mutate(Var=1:n()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(id,Var)) %>%
  mutate(Var=ifelse(Var==1,'x','y'),
         name=paste0(name,'.',Var)) %>% select(-c(Var)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from=value) %>% ungroup() %>%
  select(-id) %>%
  select(sort(current_vars())) %>% 
  mutate_each(funs = as.numeric)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
   H1.x  H1.y  H2.x  H2.y
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    10    20    30    40
2    11    21    31    41
3    12    22    32    42
4    13    23    33    43
5    14    24    34    44
6    15    25    35    45
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Should I have a code choosing N columns? The sample only has H1 and H2 but I have a total of 24 Hs.

Comment: You can use `:` operator like `H1:H24` instead of `c(H1,H2)`!

Comment: Or `c(H1:H2)` in the `separate_rows()`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data has an even number of columns:

```
nc = ncol(desired_dta)
colnames(desired_dta) = paste0("H",rep(1:(nc/2),each = 2),rep(c("_x","_y"),nc/2))
```